# J2EE Spring websphere liberty 8.5 log4j config no appenders

Tags: java, websphere

First off, I've come across lots of similar issues but I haven't been able to figure it out. Perhaps I'm missing something simple.

I have a war with log4j that runs fine on tomcat (no warning message), but on websphere liberty 8.5 I get:

```
[err] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
[err] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[err] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Has anyone come across this? In my web.xml I have

```
<!-- logging config and listener -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
```

and the log4j config file under /WEB-INF

```
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="512KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="File" value="C:/logs/application.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.valuecube.*">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="info"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

What have I done that Websphere doesn't like?

Comment: Error messages and doc seem to indicate the warning is from not finding the log4j-config.xml file from a getResource on the ThreadContextClassloader. Do you have any particular directives in the server.xml that would modify that?

Comment: Sorry to comment spam, but I just tried this by putting your log4j-config.xml into a local servlet and did a Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/WEB-INF/log4j-config.xml"), which returned the resource properly. Could you try this in your environment to see what it returns? Beyond that, you could attempt to do the same using a lookup to the context-param as well.

Comment: @ewhoch Thanks for the suggestion. Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/WEB-INF/log4j-confi‌​g.xml") returns null and request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("log4jConfigLocation") returns /WEB-INF/log4j-config.xml. I don't know what to do with it though, nothing particular in server.xml

Comment: That's likely the cause, then. Did you have any other information on your configuration or application structure? Somehow the classloader isn't getting a handle to that file, which is confusing.